# Copy command in Ubuntu without replacing existing content?

Tags: ubuntu, files

Hi how do I copy a folder from source to destination in Ubuntu without replacing the existing contents in the destination folder?

I tried `cp -r -u` and `cp -r -n`, and neither one worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that if you're copying a directory using -r, the -n will only take effect against the directory being copied, not individual files, leaving you with -i which is interactive though, which means you have to stick around to watch it go.  Not useful if you're scripting I suppose.

What can work instead if you're copying a source which has multiple directories within, is `rsync` with the `--ignore-existing` flag.  rsync can also work for local transfer, in fact, I prefer it for copying entire directory/subdir's..

Answer (score 0):

It is `cp -i` for interactive queries before overwriting. You can find more with `man cp`.